# QT: Custom QWidget constructors behavior wrong before show() is called

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qgraphicsview

I have created a custom implementation of a `QMainWindow` holding a custom `QGraphicsView`.
The View is able to be given and display an image in the background with zoom behavior, which maximizes this image in the view after being loaded while keeping aspect ratio. This behavior works well when I load an Image while the Window is already shown.

I want to give the window a `default_image` in the constructor, with the intention it being loaded up immediately. I have a function/slot to load this default image in the window, to be called again later. I use this function to also do this initialization in the windows constructor.

When I call the function in the windows or views constructor operations of setting the `sceneRect` and such do not apply correctly. The image is shown as zoomed extremely far out as if some calls to `fitInView` and `setSceneRect` were just ignored.
When I call the function after `QMainWindow::show()` has been called on the window the first time in my `main` (which is after the constructor is called, obviously),
then everything works as intended.

So why does the class have different behavior when being invisible, aka. not being `show()`n?
I can assume from this behavior that a certain class of operation is not applied to widgets when they are not shown yet. How to recognize what applies and what does not?
And how to do proper initialization in this case at any rate?

I'd love to refrain from documenting: "You just have to manually call `loadImageDefault()` after `show()` has been called!" for my users to have to account for this. It's a default, it should be able to be applied directly in the constructor.

Calling `update()` on the widgets at different levels in the constructor afterwards has not rendered any improvement.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your code -- preferably as a [mcve].  It sounds as if you're making use of certain aspects of the widget's geometry *before* it is shown -- that, generally speaking, is not reliable.

Comment: So if geometry is not set up in the background already I understand why this would cause issues. I assumed that this would already have been done during construction and the window is just not visible as the naming `setVisible`, aka `show()`, suggests.
[Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#visible-prop) suggest qt-features enabling delayed initialization as a way forward, which I would post as an answer if nothing else seems to come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems geometry is not fully or not set up in the background until a widget is `show()`n.
This will lead to problems for widgets at construction time, if construction involves geometry, like `QGraphicsView`.
Hence setting an image and zoom behavior, etc. will not ever work before `show()` has been called.

A way around this is automatic delayed initialization suggested by the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#visible-prop).
Docs suggest the use of `QEvent::Polish` here, but this did not work for me either.
Next option is to override `showEvent(QShowEvent*)`.

```
void Window::showEvent(QShowEvent* e)
{
    QMainWindow::showEvent(e);

    if (load_default_image_on_show && !default_image.isNull())
    {
        loadImageDefault();
        load_default_image_on_polish = false;
    }
}
```

`QMainWindow::showEvent()` is called before delayed initialization is handled, because I assume it contributes to the setup of geometry.
I am using a `bool load_default_image_on_show = true` as a lazy trigger. I do not particularly like having a one-use `bool`, because it expands the window class' definition, but I haven't found anything to test a widget if it has never been shown before, which could replace it. One can test for visibility, but that property can change repeatedly, so one needs the switch instead that only triggers it once.

This then works as intended and without having the user call anything additional to the constructor for initialization to be correct.